# How to know when does the table sorting is finished via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I need to know in JavaScript when does the table sorting is finished. I'm using PrimeFaces(UI library) to work with HTML tables and seems like it uses its specific tablesorter functions. I've checked their `PrimeFaces DataTable Widget` code and didn't found anything that can trigger a function when the sorting is ended.

I've also tried to do a workaround with JQuery functions like:

```
//doesn't work as request response is received earlier and after the table is sorted
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (){
   myDialog.hide();
});
```

and this approach:

```
//doesn't work, because apparently there is no change in DOM tree
$("table").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function (e){
    myDialog.hide();
});
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: how are you currently triggering the sorting?

Comment: The sorting is triggered in two ways: by clicking on table header an in some cases I'm calling Primefaces js function: `issueTableWidget.sort(sortedColumn, sortedColumn.data('sortorder'), false);`

Comment: it seems that PrimeFaces is based on jQueryUI, have you tried using a `.done()`? `issueTableWidget.sort().done(function () { myDialog.hide(); });`

Comment: Yest, it is based on jQueryUI, but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'done' of undefined` error when I'm trying `done()`.